# Virtualbox: Unable to SSH to guest from non-local network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, firewall

I have virtual `Ubuntu` server hosted by `Virtualbox`.
The virtual machine is using `bridged interface`. (The VM must have spesific IP so I use bridged interface.)

The virtual machine is on network `10.0.0.0/24`.
Other machines on the same network can ping and `SSH` to it.

However `SSH` connections from other network to the VM fail. Machines from the other network can ping the VM without problems.

I first tought this problem might be caused by firewalls so I tried disabling firewalls on both guest and host but that did not help. (I also tried creating firewall rules that allowed the other network. Firewall used in `Ubuntu` was `Ufw`.)

I have tried this on different hosts: `Ubuntu` and `Windows` server.
Version of `Virtualbox` on Windows is `5.0.12 r104815`. On `Ubuntu` it is `4.1.44-dfsg-1+deb7u1ubuntu1`. For both hosts the problem is the same: Local connections work fine but from non-local network only `ping` works.

I can `SSH` to non-Virtualbox hosted devices on the `10.0.0.0/24` network from the other network.

This clearly indicates that `Virtualbox` is somehow preveting `SSH` from foreign network but allowing `ping`.

What can do to allow other protocols than ping from foreign network?

Comment: Sounds like your device (router?) that routes between your networks (10.0.0.0 and the "other") does route icmp, but not tcp. How are the different networks connected?

Comment: I tought that at first also, but as stated in my post, `TCP` connections work between the networks. Only exception to this are VMs that are hosted on `Virtualbox`. So the TCP packets are getting trough the router.